# JavaScript countdown timer not working

Tags: javascript

I am a JavaScript newbie. I am using a template which has the code below. It shows a countdown timer. I can't understand why it does not work. I have provided it the value of 90 days. Please guide. Thanks

```
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.4.0

/*
 countdown is a simple jquery plugin for countdowns

 Dual licensed under the MIT (http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php)
 and GPL-3.0 (http://opensource.org/licenses/GPL-3.0) licenses.

 @source: http://github.com/rendro/countdown/
 @autor: Robert Fleischmann
 @version: 1.0.1
 */
```

(function () {

(function ($) {
    $.countdown = function (el, options) {
      var getDateData,
        _this = this;
      this.el = el;
      this.$el = $(el);
      this.$el.data("countdown", this);

```
  this.init = function () {
    _this.options = $.extend({}, $.countdown.defaultOptions, options);
    if (_this.options.refresh) {
      _this.interval = setInterval(function () {
        return _this.render();
      }, _this.options.refresh);
    }
    _this.render();
    return _this;
  };

  getDateData = function (endDate) {
    var dateData, diff;
    endDate = Date.parse($.isPlainObject(_this.options.date) ? _this.options.date : new Date(_this.options.date));
    diff = (endDate - Date.parse(new Date)) / 1000;
    if (diff <= 0) {
      diff = 0;
      if (_this.interval) {
        _this.stop();
      }
      _this.options.onEnd.apply(_this);
    }
    dateData = {
      years: 90,
      days: 90,
      hours: 0,
      min: 0,
      sec: 90,
      millisec: 0
    };
    if (diff >= (365.25 * 86400)) {
      dateData.years = Math.floor(diff / (365.25 * 86400));
      diff -= dateData.years * 365.25 * 86400;
    }
    if (diff >= 86400) {
      dateData.days = Math.floor(diff / 86400);
      diff -= dateData.days * 86400;
    }
    if (diff >= 3600) {
      dateData.hours = Math.floor(diff / 3600);
      diff -= dateData.hours * 3600;
    }
    if (diff >= 60) {
      dateData.min = Math.floor(diff / 60);
      diff -= dateData.min * 60;
    }
    dateData.sec = diff;

    return dateData;
  };

  this.leadingZeros = function (num, length) {
    if (length == null) {
      length = 2;
    }
    num = String(num);
    while (num.length < length) {
      num = "0" + num;
    }

    return num;
  };

  this.update = function (newDate) {
    _this.options.date = newDate;

    return _this;
  };

  this.render = function () {
    _this.options.render.apply(_this, [getDateData(_this.options.date)]);

    return _this;
  };

  this.stop = function () {
    if (_this.interval) {
      clearInterval(_this.interval);
    }
    _this.interval = null;

    return _this;
  };

  this.start = function (refresh) {
    if (refresh == null) {
      refresh = _this.options.refresh || $.countdown.defaultOptions.refresh;
    }
    if (_this.interval) {
      clearInterval(_this.interval);
    }
    _this.render();
    _this.options.refresh = refresh;
    _this.interval = setInterval(function () {
      return _this.render();
    }, _this.options.refresh);

    return _this;
  };

  return this.init();
};

$.countdown.defaultOptions = {
  date: "June 7, 2087 15:03:25",
  refresh: 1000,
  onEnd: $.noop,
  render: function (date) {
    return $(this.el).html("" + date.years + " years, " + date.days + " days, " + (this.leadingZeros(date.hours)) + " hours, " + (this.leadingZeros(date.min)) + " min and " + (this.leadingZeros(date.sec)) + " sec");
  }
};

$.fn.countdown = function (options) {
  return $.each(this, function (i, el) {
    var $el;
    $el = $(el);
    if (!$el.data('countdown')) {
      return $el.data('countdown', new $.countdown(el, options));
    }
  });
};

return void 0;
```

})(jQuery);

}).call(this);

Comment: what about it does not work?can you make a jsfiddle example

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/r565sn9j/2/

Comment: @ArunPJohny: Wonder why its not working here:
http://sungoldorganic.com/

Comment: The problem is the date format.... `var endDate = "December  27, 2014 15:03:25";`  - it is not able to parse the above format

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```
endDate = Date.parse($.isPlainObject(_this.options.date)
    ? _this.options.date : new Date(_this.options.date));
```

to

```
endDate = Date.parse($.isPlainObject(_this.options.date)
    ? _this.options.date : new Date(year,month,date));
```

example:

```
endDate = Date.parse($.isPlainObject(_this.options.date)
    ? _this.options.date : new Date(2017,02,15));
```